# Oriental TeX and Husayni

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, context, arabic

I have recently been typesetting a Quranic Mashaf using a combination of XeLaTeX, bidi, and polyglossia. I am generally pleased with the results so far, but after reviewing Idris Samawi Hamid's work in ConTEXT and the development of the Husayni font, I believe that's the direction I'd like to move in.

But I'm unclear if Husayni is complete yet? The last reference I could find is in the article [Oriental TEX: optimizing paragraphs](https://www.academia.edu/11575330/Oriental_TeX_optimizing_paragraphs) which dates back to 2012, and at that time the font was still under development. I wrote to Professor Idris  recently but haven't heard back yet.

Could anyone provide a "minimal working document" that illustrates the use of Husayni?

Lastly, as a computer programmer, and the idea of being able to program TeX in a language like Lua seems very appealing. However, I'm unclear how mature LuaTeX and the rest of the stack that Professor Idris uses *actually is*, or whether it's missing features that will soon frustrate me and make me want to go back to XeLaTeX? Any advice from someone who's been down that road would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Luatex is gearing towards v1.0 release and will be soon out of beta. So,  it is fairly mature now.  ConTeXt MkIV makes extensive use of luatex (more than 50% of processing takes place in the lua end). However, I don't use non-English fonts, so I don't know how the font functionality compares with xetex.